# Dismiss keyboard when uitableview cell is selected and using UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, resignfirstresponder

So I have an app that is basically a movie search app displayed using a UITableViewController and a UISearchController.

I have a cell that when tapped, loads more results. But when I tap it, I also want the keyboard to go away. So in the `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method, I assume I have to call `resignFirstResponder()`. The problem is that it doesn't work. I've tried everything but nothing makes the keyboard disappear. I think it's because the keyboard is part of the UISearchBar, and I should call `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()`. The problem is that I can't access the searchBar from my `UITableViewController` class.

Here is what I have, none of this works:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //Remove Keyboard
            self.resignFirstResponder()
            self.view.resignFirstResponder()
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            self.tableView.endEditing(true)
            self.navigationController?.view.endEditing(true)
            self.navigationController?.resignFirstResponder()

        //Do a bunch of other stuff..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the `searchBar` is the first responder then either:

1. Pass a reference to the `searchBar` to the `UITableViewController`
2. Use KVC: Post a notification that you're loading more results and keyboard should be hidden, and in your `UISeachController` listen for that notification.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that. Isn't it inefficient to do so? It worked, though. Thanks!

Comment: Why would it be inefficient? Delegation is the best solution, but you could use notifications as well if you don't want to pass references.

Comment: When I set a `tableview`'s "searchBar" variable to `SearchController.SearchBar` I'm assigning by reference right? If so, then that would be the most efficient and clutter free way.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder)
                                                 to:nil
                                               from:nil
                                           forEvent:nil];
```